# Plotting discrete predictions with probability intervals - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot some discrete predictions with probability intervals in ggplot2, but I'm having some problems.

I have the following data.frame

```
city    pred    min.80    max.80
BH      100     50        150
RJ      120     80        140
SP      90      80        100
```

I want a plot with the cities on y-axis and the predicted values on x-axis. For each discrete value of y, there should be a horizontal bar with its range being the min.80 and max.80 values. My idea is to use `geom_rect` from `ggplot2` for doing it.

I've tried the following code, but the problem is that I'm converting the discrete variable to continuous in order to plot it, and I lose their values on the label.

```
> ggplot(df) + geom_rect(aes(xmin=min.80, xmax=max.80, ymin=as.numeric(city)-0.4,
+ ymax=as.numeric(city)+0.4))
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the geom `pointrange` or `crossbar`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=city)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=min.80, ymax=max.80, y=pred)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=city)) + 
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin=min.80, ymax=max.80, y=pred)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. FYI: `stat = "identity"` is the default for both, I believe.

Comment: @joran Nice catch, thank you. I started to write a solution using `geom_bar` and the `stat="identity"` was an artefact from that...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to keep the y axis as a factor (`y=city`). This kind of (estimate+interval) data is probably is better done with something like `geom_pointrange`. After all, the "height" of the rectangle doesn't have an interpretation.

If you have to have the errorbars be horizontal, I've done this before in two ways:

1. using `coord_flip()`
2. Last time I tried `coord_flip()`, it was a bit limited, so I sometimes also recreated the `geom_pointrange()` functionality by combining `geom_hline()` with `geom_point()`.